# c# razor mvc textboxfor in foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, view, model, foreach

how is it possible to retrieve data from `TextBoxFor` helper within a foreach loop? I mean:

in the view:

```
foreach(Language l in ViewBag.Languages){
    <td>@l.lang</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
}
```

and how can I retrieve it in the controller once posted?

```
MyModel.Name //this returns the value of the first textbox within the foreach loop
```

By the way model.Name is defined in MyModel.cs as:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `ModelBinder` in your action by using:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string[] name)
{
    foreach (var item in name)
    {
        // Process items
    }
}
```

Where `name` is the name automatically given to the text-boxes by `Html.TextBoxFor()`.

---

*Edit*: If you wish to change the parameter name from `name` to something more descriptive, you can achieve this by using `Html.TextBox`, albeit with a loss of stong-typing:

```
@Html.TextBox("SomeMoreDescriptiveName", Model.Name);
```

And then in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string[] SomeMoreDescriptiveName)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: what if I am passing a model as a parameter? I mean, if the controller is like this: public ActionResult(MyModel model) and I am getting the values from the model?

Comment: As long as you have `string[] Name { get; set; }` on you model, the default ModelBinder will still be able to bind to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach (var _item in Model.ListSurvey)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Question, new { Value = @_item.Question })

}
```